# Substituir e concatenação o conteúdo de uma célula

Tags: vba, excel-vba, replace

Primeiramente eu filtro o conteúdo de uma coluna da tabela para obter tudo o que não contém `/`.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*/*"
```

Com esse resultado, gostaria de substituir o conteúdo das células pelo próprio conteúdo dela concatenado com a string `/SUP`. Para isso uso o `Selection.Replace`:

```
Selection.Replace What:="???", Replacement:="???/SUP", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Mas não está funcionando...

O resultado esperado seria:

```
cellCOM/ --- replace --- cellCOM/
cellSEM  --- replace --- cellSEM/SUP
```

Como posso pegar o conteúdo da célula na hora de fazer essa substituição??

Teria uma forma diferente ou melhor de se fazer isso??

Comment: Depois de filtrar, você não pode usar o `Selection`, na verdade é sempre bom evitar o uso de `Select`. Mas após o filtro você precisa utilizar as células visíveis para utilizar a função `replace`

Comment: @danieltakeshi Certo. E caso não tenha células visíveis?? como procedo?

Comment: Cria uma condicional para verificar se há células visíveis (`Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`), caso possua trata os dados, caso contrário sai da condicional ou fornece uma mensagem de aviso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu teria uma abordagem diferente. Dadas as informações, pelo que eu entendi, você não precisa fazer nenhum filtro. Talvez você queira somente fazer um filtro após, para ver o que foi mudado (e para isso você teria que mudar o filtro).
Então, você precisa somente fazer um loop e substituir "tudo que não contém /", certo?

Usando a função InStr você descobre se há ou não o "/". Caso não encontre, o retorno é zero, e ele entra no "If" para substituir o valor atual da célula por ele mesmo com o  "/SUP"

```
Sub substituir_por_barraSUP()

Dim lngUltimaLinha As Long
Dim i As Integer

'Existem outras formas encontrar a última linha,
'Nesse casom estou considerando que você tem todos os dados na coluna 1, ou A.
lngUltimaLinha = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop começando a partir da segunda linha, considerando que a primeira linha é o cabeçalho
For i = 2 To lngUltimaLinha
    If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "/") = 0 Then
     Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & "/SUP"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Antes:

```
Header
cellCOM/
cellSEM
cellCOM/
cellSEM
cellCOM/
cellSEM
```

Depois:

```
Header
cellCOM/
cellSEM/SUP
cellCOM/
cellSEM/SUP
cellCOM/
cellSEM/SUP
```

Comment: Fazer um loop daria certo também. Só optei pelo filtro e pelo método replace pois achei que iria ser mais otimizado do que varrer todas as células da planilha.